# Activity shown as a Dialog have a toolbar

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an issue. I have an `activity` and I show it as a `dialog` see the pic.

[This image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keCRa.png)

In this picture there is a `dialog` which have a small black `toolbar` I think, how to remove it.

I use this style for the activity

```
style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"
```

This is Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    ///////////////
    <activity android:name=".Activity2"
        />

    //////////////////////////////
    <activity android:name=".events.Wedding_Ceremony"/>

    /////////////////

    <activity android:name=".events.GalleryView"/>
    /////////////////////

    <activity android:name=".events.SingleViewActivity"/>

    ///////////// this is my Dialog
    <activity android:name=".downloadDialog.MainDialog"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert"
        />
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

You should reference to your style file:

```
<activity android:name=".downloadDialog.MainDialog"
    android:theme="@style/MyAlertDialogStyle"
/>
```

Comment: thnkx for the reply.but  it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Try with the update, windowNoTitle should work with AppCompatActivity